# Why a signed apk says: app not installed, but vs code runs it perfectly

Tags: flutter

Could you help me why installing an apk says: The app is not installed. (Tested another android phone with the same result)

I have created the default flutter app with the same command: "flutter build apk" and it installs correctly.

My app using google_ sign_in package and signed with keystore. On the very same andrid device the usb driven application from VS Code runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

For the final release you can use the following command to generate `APK` or `appbundle` for release.

Appbundle:

```
flutter build appbundle --no-tree-shake-icons --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --release
```

APK:

```
flutter build apk --no-tree-shake-icons --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --release
```

Answer (score 0):

> first uninstall the older app which is installed by debugging usb
> Then Install the release apk

The signature mismatches with debug and release apk so you may get app not installed msg!!!

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter build apk --release` for release version and go to your
`AppName>build>app>outputs>apk>release` you will find it there.